# How to extrude faces inward and outward sphere together

Tags: extrude

I need Your help with extrusion. Can't figure out how to extrude something like window frames on a spheric surface and make them solid, while window surfaces must remain flat.
When I extrude faces along normals, then it solidifies my window surface as shown in the screenshot 2 below.
Basically, I want to extrude windows frames simultaneously inward sphere and outward sphere.
How can I achieve that?
Thank You!

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: the image is not clear in message, as the image looks like an extrusion and not a solidify.  please clarify a bit simpler if the image does not show the details, thanks.  clarify frames or panes. are you extruding one other or both?

Comment: Hi, Dave. I tried extrusion, not solidification. I believe, u can't solidify separate faces of an object. My target is to leave  windows plain and make frames more thick, while leaving windows thin. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but to keep an extrusion "solid", use shift+d to duplicate the faces first, then right click to make them snap back to their original position, and then extrude. This will give an extrusion with 2 faces - the original face and the extruded one. If you need to extrude inwards as well after that, you can do it from the inside faces.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, Christopher! I didn’t know that I need to create extra face before extrusion. I thought that what extrusion does - creates one more face and moves it in direction you want... I will try duplicate first, thanks

Comment: Let me try to explain my question further. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning. Initially frames and windows faces are lying in same plane to each other. So I want bigger faces (windows) to stay where they are and same thin as they were. Frames are required to be “extruded” inwards and outwards, thus becoming solidified. When I’m trying to extrude faces of frames along normals, I get result as shown in screenshot 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "separate objects" when in edit mode and you have the window panes selected. Put them in a separate grouping. Then tab out of edit mode, use solidify on the frame, and not on the panes group.  Parent the panes to the frame for scale adjustments as "parent object" in object mode, select panes-object first, shift+click frame and apply parenting (right click or menu etc).  The panes will have the thin non-solidified thickness and the frame will still have a solidify you apply, adjust as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dave! I'm at work next 4 days. Will try after that and reply back.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dave! I finally reached my home PC and tried a method You suggested. It worked. However, I'm now curious if there is a way to place my panes to be in the middle of the frame, so that frames to have a ledge at the outside and inside the sphere.

Comment: Hope these screen shots will clarify what I mean:
https://prnt.sc/ttlqwb
https://prnt.sc/ttlqhl

Comment: yes.  simply adjust the frame solidify modifier.  the +- 1 is the inside or outside adjustment to move the frame solidify on the inside or outside more. You can use the solidify thickness, but if that makes the frame too wide, then try shrink fatten on the scaled axis (destructive so save another copy) or use push-pull.  Warning, this slightly scales also if in edit mode.  But as I recall it is fine for object mode to push-pull the panes from centre point.  Adjust your pivot point with  (.) as necessary.  I put push-pull on (Q) key because it is in the corner drop down menu at top left.